# shared_ptr - accessing from within the contained object

Tags: c++

### Environment

- Ubuntu x64 OS
- C++

### Use-case

- `SomeObj` is a class accessed in multi-threaded manner, and, should cleanup only after all of it's associated threads have shutdown
- `SomeObj` is controlling the life time of it's associated threads
- Having `SomeObj` destructed before all of the associated threads have gracefully terminated might lead to 'Segmentation fault' when any of the threads is trying to access the destructed `SomeObj`
- To avoid that, a ref-count is to be managed such that the obj is not destructed as-long as it's ref count is larger than zero, this way, each thread holds a ref to the obj during it's life-time, and thus, the obj is removed from memory ( suicide ) only when it's ref hits zero.
- this approach guarantees the obj will only die after all of it's associated threads have terminated, and does that without the need of a waitable obj ( eg. `std::mutex` )

### Considered implementation

- The obj lifetime is managed using `std::shared_ptr`
- `std::shared_ptr` already maintains a ref count for the object
- The `shared_ptr` is maintained by external code
- Given `std::shared_ptr<SomeObj>`, if only `SomeObj` could have access to the `shared_ptr` ref count it could then be used to reference each of it's associated threads... or, in other words, if `SomeObj` could have held a `std::shared_pt<this>` for each of it's associated threads.

### Question at hand

**Given `std::shared_ptr<SomeObj>`, can `SomeObj` access the ref maintained by `std::shared_ptr<SomeObj>`, or, hold a eg. `std::shared_ptr<this>` ?**

Comment: If *`SomeObj` is controlling the life time of it's associated threads* why doesn't it just call `join` in the destructor so it can't die until all the threads are finished?

Comment: because then it would block, wait for termination, and, hold the calling thread... I want to avoid that...

Comment: `use_count` (the reference counter) can be approximative, and `unique` is deprecated since C++17 and will be removed in C++20 specifically because `use_count` is approximative. You may be better off using some form of wrapper and relying on the destructor. I'm not sure if there is a reliable way of using the reference counter for anything useful.

Comment: Okay, why not pass a copy of the `shared_ptr` to all the threads?  Then, they all share the same object, but that object can't die until all of the threads are done and the call site `shared_ptr` is destroyed.

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with the `STL` (containers and algorithms) parts of the Standard Library.

Comment: @NathanOliver I can do that though it seems to me like a workaround/patch, and not what std::shared_ptr was originally intended for... it will req me to externally create the object `std::shared_ptr<SomeObj>` and then pass the 'shared_ptr' back into `SomeObj`...

Comment: @NadavRub Are you aware of [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)?

Comment: Thanks @alterigel, this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alter igel:

> @NadavRub Are you aware of `std::enable_shared_from_this`?

NadavRub:

> Thanks @alterigel, this is exactly what I need.